# Issue creating directory using c#

Tags: c#, winforms

I have to create a directory using some Korean characters the end text becomes something like :

```
2016.07.12 09:20(제휴) 캠블리 영어 완성 1+1 이벤트
```

I am using this to create directory:

```
 Directory.CreateDirectory(folderpath + "\\" + dName);
```

But i get Error :

```
The given path's format is not supported."
```

But if i manually go to explorer create new folder paste that text it takes it fine and makes a new directory any suggestion ?

Comment: what is the value for `folderpath` and `dName`

Comment: Read https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365247

Comment: paths are correct if i just use dname= test it works fine , when i use dname as the value above i get the error.\

Comment: Aside: use Path.Combine() instead of concatenation of strings with the double back slash.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Windows, the `:` character isn't supported in file paths.

[This MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247(v=vs.85).aspx#naming_conventions) lists the characters that cannot be used in paths:

> Use any character in the current code page for a name, including Unicode characters and characters in the extended character set (128–255), except for the following:
>
> The following reserved characters:
>
> - < (less than)
> - > (greater than)
> - : (colon)
> - " (double quote)
> - / (forward slash)
> - \ (backslash)
> - | (vertical bar or pipe)
> - ? (question mark)
> - * (asterisk)
> - Integer value zero, sometimes referred to as the ASCII NUL character.
> - Characters whose integer representations are in the range from 1 through 31, except for alternate data streams where these characters are allowed. For more information about file streams, see File Streams.
> - Any other character that the target file system does not allow.

Comment: But as i said paste the above and it works when you do manually maybe i ignore the : let me check again

Comment: @confusedMind I'm not sure why explorer lets you create that, as it shouldn't. Maybe it's a [full width colon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colon_(punctuation)#Encoding) or something like that that is being created when you enter it in manually?

Comment: You are rite : is not allowed maybe i remove it on explorer, if i remove on the code it works fine thank you for pointing that out

Answer (score 1):

What do you get when trying to print `folderpath + "\\" + dName`? is it the full path and requested directory name?

Refer to the examples provided at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/54a0at6s(v=vs.110).aspx and make sure you formatted the path correctly.